# Why do we have an [authors] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I was kind of surprised to see the [authors](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authors) tag up and about.

The tag wiki excerpt reads this (emphasis mine)

> For questions which are explicitly about the author of the work. **Do not use this tag unless your question directly relates to some literary aspect of an author's life (motivation for writing, beliefs that impacted writing, etc.)**

Isn't that the purpose of a specific author tag, such as [george-orwell](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-orwell)?

The tag does nothing. Let's burninate it.

Comment: This feels very similar to the situation of [the \[behind-the-scenes\] tag](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/q/338/43) that currently looks slated for burnination. There's tags like [tag:inspiration], [tag:symbolism], [tag:meaning], [tag:religion], [tag:story-motivation], for indicating the part of an author's life you're asking about (in combination with an author tag, as you've noted).

Comment: @doppelgreener Behind the scenes isn't burninated yet? I thought it was for a second. That's one of the tags I first thought about when I saw this.

Comment: Its burnination proposal is only 3-4 days old, there's no need to rush into it. Someone partially burninated it away after only 2 hours on Sunday [but we spoke in chat about waiting a bit longer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35080818#35080818). It's important to ensure the community gets a chance to weigh in on these things. It'll be worth acting on it in a couple of days if things look settled (which they do currently).

Comment: @doppelgreener *sigh* Things are moving to quickly for me. I thought it was around a week old, and had been done already :P Speaking of which, a couple of days for a private beta is generally equal to a week :P